# Evaluating multiple elements or keys-value in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

My input data sample looks like this(Country,Zone,Temperature)

```
Ind,Z1,10
Jap,Z2,20
Ind,Z1,30
Ind,Z2,10
Jap,Z1,20
```

Requirement is summing up Temperature for respective Zones.

Output should be like

```
Ind,Z1,40
Ind,Z2,10
Jap,Z1,20
```

....so on
I know we can simply filter out Country and sum up the Temperature per Zone with reduceByKey(zone being the key) but I dont want to do that.

How can we achieve this using RDD's or dataframes?
Because our data should be evaluated based on country(zone,Temperature)

I am not sure how to use key value pairs and evaluate them for Country.

Comment: `map` to make a rdd of `(country, zone), temperature)` then `reduceByKey`

Comment: thanks @TheArchetypalPaul!

Answer (score 1):

It was simple after @the archetypal Pauls suggestion of ((k1,k2),v)

```
val thirdRDD = baseRDD.map(x => x.split(","))
                      .map(x => ((x(0), x(1)),x(2).trim().toInt))
                      .reduceByKey(_+_)
```

Thanks!